# $resource:badcfg Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array

Tags: angularjs, rest, ngresource

I have following Service, the `query` always returns an array.

```
.factory('ClosingDocService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("http://localhost:5001/api/ClosingDoc/:id",
                    { id: "@id" },
                    {
                        'query': { method: 'GET' },
                        'save': { method: 'POST', transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } }
                    });
}])
```

However, the following call always got the error?

```
ClosingDocService.query({ category: model.category }).$promise
.then(function (x) { });
```

Using fiddler shows the following correct url has been called and the values were returned.

```
http://localhost:5001/api/ClosingDoc?category=XXX
```

Error:

> angular.js:13920 Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - adding `isArray: true`. But why?

```
'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to how `$resource` object methods are handled.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) on `$resource`:

> It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a callback function for the action methods.

Essentially, unless you provide `isArray: true`, the `$resource` object method **pre-allocates** an `Object` for the data that is to be returned.  When the data being returned actually ends up being an array, that data can't be populated into the pre-allocated object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too. What worked for me was the following fix

Changing the `query` to `get` as follows:

```
ClosingDocService.get({ category: model.category }).$promise
.then(function (x) { });
```